# How to return HTTP response when the result need to wait for Kafka event finish first

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka with Spring Boot. Is it possible to return the HTTP response when the result need to wait for Kafka event finish first?

I have some services and sub-processes. *Service A* receives HTTP request from user and it sends message to Kafka in order to do some sub-processes. Before *service A* returns the HTTP response, it needs to wait for *service B* to update the record in database.

[image]

Comment: You should return `201:Accepted` status, and not wait

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better if service B produces the "done" message to a different Kafka topic and service A consumes it if you want to implement event driven model, as service A should not be aware and care about what happens behind the scenes, the DB update in this case.

And regarding how service A can wait and return, here's my idea in a conceptual code:

```
class RestController {
getInfo(input){
  Future future = KF_bean.produce(input,random_req_id)
  return future.get()
}
} 

class KF_bean {

Map map = Hashmap...

CompletableFuture produce(input, random_req_id){
   kafkalib.produce(input).withHeader(random_req_id)
future = new CompletableFuture()
   map.put(random_req_id, future)
   return future
} 

void onConsume(msg){
   req_id = msg.getHeader("vin")
   map.get(req_id).complete()
} 

}
```

It should work if none of instances of the service A are in same consumer group, or they should be group less consumers.

Comment: How to create groupless consumers? I can't find any. If that's not possible, how to ensure that the consumer group ids are unique for every instances? Especially in container based architecture where instances can be brought up and teared down as needed